# c# Каналы (pipes) Возможна ли обратная передача данных?

Tags: c#

Приложение 1 (Клиент) получил данные и передал их Приложению 2 (Сервер).
Сервер их обработал и отдал обратно Клиенту.
Всё происходит локально на одной машинке, pipe анонимный.

Такое возможно?
Во всех примерах только про одностороннее взаимодействие.

Comment: Если клиент на другой машине, WebSocket например, а если на этой же, то Named Pipe.

Comment: "Анонимные каналы обеспечивают межпроцессное взаимодействие на локальном компьютере" -  не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется возможно. Вам необходимо создать TCP/UDP/HTTP/HTTPS подключение между сервером и клиентом, для ваших целей TCP подходит лучше всего. Ищите методы шифрования в интернете

Comment: Обычный  using (pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("ХХХ", PipeDirection.InOut))
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(pipeServer))
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(pipeServer))   не подойдёт?

Comment: ok, видимо вот ответ https://metanit.com/sharp/net/4.5.php спасибо!